# Can't get specific links instead of all

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

I've written a script to parse links from a site. There are 24 links in the left sided bar in that page. my script can parse them all. However, i would like to get the first 20 links only. What can I do at this moment?

Here is the script I'm trying with now:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

response = requests.get("http://www.trmsites.com/shop/home.asp?siteid=90122").text
tree = html.fromstring(response)
for titles in tree.xpath("//td[@class='leftnav']/a/@href"):
    print(titles)
```

Comment: You should be able to slice the result of xpath: `for titles in tree.xpath("//td[@class='leftnav']/a/@href")[:20]:`

Comment: What about storing the result in a list `ls = tree.xpath("//td[@class='leftnav']/a/@href")` and then slicing the list `print(ls[:20])`?

Comment: @Jkdc You were first.

Comment: Extremely sorry for my delayed response. All the given solutions rock. Thanks everyone for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tree.xpath("//td[@class='leftnav']/a/@href")` is a list. You can slice it.

```
tree.xpath("//td[@class='leftnav']/a/@href")[:20]
```

Comment: Thanks Batman for your answer. I'm not around my pc. As soon as I'm I'll give you a feedback.